# Can the coordinate of any point that a person looks at be determined from the photo of his eyes?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I am planning to develop a program in MATLAB/Python that can detect the coordinate of any point in space that a person is looking at. I was hoping to do it by placing a headset with a camera installed before eyes and tracking the pupil of the both eyes. I still don't know if it is possible. That's why I need help.

Comment: Here is a good article for what you are going to do https://www.learnopencv.com/facial-landmark-detection/

Comment: @HaBom: this article is about facial features. The OP is looking at the eyes only.

Comment: @YvesDaoust there is a part in the article talking about CLM-framework for head pose estimation that I think it can help him a little bit.

Comment: @HaBom: head pose from cameras on a headset is just impossible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust oh yes, I missed that information. So the task becomes more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenging task.

To some extent, you can determine the outline of the pupils, and a little of the iris, by image processing. Then fitting an ellipse to these and a little geometry from the ellipse axis gives you an approximate direction of gaze. Then drawing two rays from the eyes and following these directions will give you a point of convergence.

The coordinates you will obtain will be relative to the image plane, i.e. to the position of the camera, which will move with the head.

Anyway, exact outlining of ellipses will be inaccurate, the rays will fail to cross exactly, cornea refraction and perspective will alter the measurements, the glasses will move a little, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @YvesDaoust, for understanding the context and helping. I think that to estimate the two rays, I may need the center of the eyeball but that is not possible, is it? from the curvature of the eye? I don't know. I think this project needs some professional expertise to be successfully completed.

Comment: @user3660102: no, you only need the ellipse in the image plane, which you backproject to a circle in 3D. The project can work if you have low expectations on accuracy. You also need cameras on the glasses that look at the scene rather than the eyes.